# how to set spring amqp publisher confirms and returns?

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp

I am a newer to spring amqp.
When config spring amqp publisher Confirms and returns , met problems .

amqp config :

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory, @Qualifier("topicListenerAdapter")MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

    connectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(5);
    connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
    connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("request.queue","reply.queue");
    container.setMessageConverter(json2MessageConverter());
    container.setReceiveTimeout(3000);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);

    return container;
}
```

send message:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("spring-boots5", message);
        rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(new ConfirmCallback(){

            @Override
            public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("confirm correlationData is : "+correlationData+"ack is : "+
                ack);
            }

        });
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
```

When running this application , amqp message received :

```
Body:'This is my first message'MessageProperties [headers={bar=baz}, timestamp=null, messageId=123456, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=request.queue, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0]) >
```

met en error :

```
22 20:48:08.661[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m37792[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ 127.0.0.1:5672][0;39m [36mo.s.a.r.s.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No listener for seq:1
```

> And no expecting string on console :
>
> **"confirm correlationData is : "+correlationData+"ack is : "+
>                 ack**
>
> And not know how to config Reply Messaging (i use java config)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `ConfirmCallback` (and `ReturnCallback`) before sending the message.

You also need to supply some correlation data on the send so you can determine which outbound message the confirm is for.

See [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplatePublisherCallbacksIntegrationTests.java#L205)...

```
@Test
public void testPublisherConfirmWithSendAndReceive() throws Exception {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final AtomicReference<CorrelationData> confirmCD = new AtomicReference<CorrelationData>();
    templateWithConfirmsEnabled.setConfirmCallback(new ConfirmCallback() {

        @Override
        public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
            confirmCD.set(correlationData);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(this.connectionFactoryWithConfirmsEnabled);
    container.setQueueNames(ROUTE);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new Object() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public String handleMessage(String in) {
            return in.toUpperCase();
        }
    }));
    container.start();
    CorrelationData correlationData = new CorrelationData("abc");
    String result = (String) this.templateWithConfirmsEnabled.convertSendAndReceive(ROUTE, (Object) "message", correlationData);
    container.stop();
    assertEquals("MESSAGE", result);
    assertTrue(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    assertEquals(correlationData, confirmCD.get());
}
```

Comment: I have adjusted `ConfirmCallback (and ReturnCallback)` position to **Sending message** before .  Because i'm a  newer , i do not know how to set them (correlation data,reply queue ) , have some examples? thanks!

Comment: See [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplatePublisherCallbacksIntegrationTests.java#L205) - I copied it into my answer.

Comment: the `rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive` result is correct . But,   `confirmCD.get() is : null` and en error `[ 127.0.0.1:5672] [o.s.a.r.s.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl  :  No listener for seq:1`  not know the reason ...

Comment: Please show your complete test case - everything - edit your question.

Comment: I put it in [link](https://github.com/keryhu/amqp/tree/master/spring-amqp/confirm-rabbit )

Comment: But the readme shows `confirmCD.get() is : CorrelationData [id=abc]` so  it's working - so what's the problem?

Comment: very strangely !  i restart the STS,  the console error appears : `confirmCD.get() is : null` and `PublisherCallbackChannelImpl  : No listener for seq:1`

Comment: i restart the STS again ,  `confirmCD.get() is : CorrelationData [id=abc]` appears !  but  There has been `PublisherCallbackChannelImpl : No listener for seq:1`  ,, not know why restarting influences it ..

Comment: Ah - the error message (`no listener for seq`) is for the reply - you could use a different connection factory for the consumer - one that doesn't have confirms enabled. In the next version (1.5.5, 1.6.0), we have changed that log to DEBUG only.

Comment: I have modified the program as you suggest , and the ( `no listener for seq` ) disappeared . But the error ( `confirmCD.get() is : null`) is still there, i put the whole code and export from terminal in https://github.com/keryhu/amqp/tree/master/spring-amqp/confirm-rabbit   Maybe there is some mistake in my program , but not  knowing how resolve it .

Comment: You now have 2 container beans and the second one is winning; hence the connection factory is not enabled for confirms/returns. You can go back to yesterday and upgrade to 1.5.5.RELEASE which removes that error log.

Comment: I add the 1.5.5 explicitly in the pom, and remove the reply connect to recover to yesterday , but the error is still there (`confirmCD.get() is : null`) ,whole is there  https://github.com/keryhu/amqp/tree/master/spring-amqp/confirm-rabbit

Comment: The very strange thing is  that `confirmCD.get() is : CorrelationData [id=abc]  `appears  sometimes  ,and `confirmCD.get() is : null` appears sometimes .when restarting the program .

Comment: I just tested your latest version and it worked fine for me `confirmCD.get() is : CorrelationData [id=abc]
result is : HELLO` - the problem is you are (sometimes) getting the result before the confirm - you need to use the latch like the test I pointed to you does.